# Unexpected Error : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'resultData.data', line 1, position 184

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I don't understand what is problem clearly. When I searched it in google, I don't decide my reponse model is problem or the json response is problem and should change. Which one? I can't find solution for Kotlin. How I should solve this?

response JSON:

```
"data":{
      "productInfo":{
         "data":{
            "toBarcode":"2704439285463",
            "productJson":{
               "p_no":"28420000",
               "p_name":"ASA"
            }
         }
      },
      "moves":{
         "data":[
            {
               "fisAcik":"MALVERENDEN",
               "toBarcode":"2704439285463",
               "toJson":{
                  "to_Hks_Adi":"DAĞITIM MERKEZİ"
               },
               "movementJson":{
                  "isleme_Tarihi":"21/12/2022 02:19:30"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Data.kt

```
data class Data(
        val productInfo: ProductInfo,
        val moves: Moves
    )
    
    data class Moves (
        val data: List<MovesItem>
    )
    
    data class MovesItem (
        @SerializedName("fisAcik")
        val receiptExplanation: String,
        val toBarcode: String,
        val toJson: ToJson,
        val movementJson: MovementJson
    )
    
    data class MovementJson (
        @SerializedName("isleme_Tarihi")
        val processDate: String
    )
    
    data class ToJson (
        @SerializedName("to_Hks_Adi")
        val toUnitHksName: String
    )
    
    data class ProductInfo (
        val data: ProductInfoItems
    )
    
    data class ProductInfoItems (
        val toBarcode: String,
        val productJson: ProductJson
    )
    
    data class ProductJson (
        @SerializedName("p_No")
        val migrosProductNo: String,
        @SerializedName("p_Name")
        val migrosProductName: String
    )
```

method that using to call request.

```
suspend fun dataGetInfo(@Body request: DataRequest): NetworkResult<BaseResponse<Data>>
```

Comment: Can you give more of a stack trace please?  .... where in the JSON is the 184th character - it seems like a single line of JSON

Comment: @AndrewL I don't know too where is 184th character. This is full response. `BaseResponse(data=Data(productInfo=null, moves=null), success=false, errorMessage=ErrorMessage(errorCode=9900, systemMessage=Unexpected Error : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'resultData.data', line 1, position 184., userMessage=, isSystemError=true), validationErrorMessages=null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was from my wrong request. I saw Ios has same error also when request with wrong value. So, for who will look this quesiton, they should understand it's not from response or kotlin. Check your value it is clearly what request need.

Answer (score 0):

The framework you are using for this:
`...fun dataGetInfo(@Body request: DataRequest)...`
is implicitly taking a JSON request and deserializing.

The annotation `@SerializedName` is a from the **Gson** library, so I guessed that your framework must be using Gson.  From that I was able to test using:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

println(Gson().fromJson(src, Data::class.java))
```

which produces

```
Data(productInfo=ProductInfo(data=ProductInfoItems(toBarcode=2704439285463, productJson=ProductJson(migrosProductNo=null, migrosProductName=null))), moves=Moves(data=[MovesItem(receiptExplanation=MALVERENDEN, toBarcode=2704439285463, toJson=ToJson(toUnitHksName=DAĞITIM MERKEZİ), movementJson=MovementJson(processDate=21/12/2022 02:19:30))]))
```

So fundamentally your code is ok, but I think the problem is how the source JSON is "topped and tailed".  To get that parse work, I was using

```
    val src = """
        {
          "productInfo": {
            "data": {
              "toBarcode": "2704439285463",
              "productJson": {
                "p_no": "28420000",
                "p_name": "ASA"
              }
            }
          },
          "moves": {
            "data": [
              {
                "fisAcik": "MALVERENDEN",
                "toBarcode": "2704439285463",
                "toJson": {
                  "to_Hks_Adi": "DAĞITIM MERKEZİ"
                },
                "movementJson": {
                  "isleme_Tarihi": "21/12/2022 02:19:30"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
            """
```

Notice how I removed, from your source, `"data":` since what you pasted is obviously not a JSON document.  I guess, therefore, that this is where the problem occurs - something to do with the top or bottom of the JSON document *or* you need a container object around the JSON for `Data`

Comment: `data class BaseResponse<T>(
    val data: T,
    val success: Boolean?,
    val errorMessage: ErrorMessage?,
    @SerializedName("validatonErrorMessages") val validationErrorMessages: List<ValidationErrorMessage>?
)` This is my `BaseResponse` that should be container data. But don't work in here. Also ios developers can get successfull response from this json. So, I can't want to change json. I don't why BaseResponse don't work.